# Android program compiles with no errors,but refuses to install

Tags: android

i've posted this question earlier,but could'nt get any solutions.Please i really do need help.After following a couple of tutorials,i have written a ListFragment application which compiles with no erros,but refuses to install on AVD which has API 17,android 4.2.2

```
[2014-05-09 20:27:44 - Carrebeanne] Failed to install Carrebeanne.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2014-05-09 20:27:44 - Carrebeanne] (null)
[2014-05-09 20:27:44 - Carrebeanne] Launch canceled!
```

Please What i'm i suppposed to do?I've been stuck here for 2 days now

Comment: Have you tried installing it on a real device instead of an emulator? The logs say nothing.

Comment: It installs well,but closes immediately it opens up